# Trying to write a MIPS Assembler

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Getting undeclared variable compiling errors seen below when i debug with gcd online

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQ5mbJk.o: in function \`assemble':
main.c:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to \`parseInstruction'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to \`getRegisterNumber'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x338): undefined reference to \`getRegisterNumber'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to \`getRegisterNumber'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x463): undefined reference to \`parseDirective'
```

I need help or suggestions fixing the main and void sections underneath. All previous functions are defined in my source file

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Checking command line arguments
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <test.asm> <test.out>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Initializing memory 
    int text_segment[MAX_SIZE];
    int data_segment[MAX_SIZE];
    memset(text_segment, 0, MAX_SIZE);
    memset(data_segment, 0, MAX_SIZE);

    // Writing to output file
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    fwrite(text_segment, 1, MAX_SIZE, fp);
    fwrite(data_segment, 1, MAX_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
// Assembling the input file
void assemble(char* filename, int* text_segment, int* data_segment) {
    int line_number = 0;
    int text_offset = 0;
    int data_offset = 0;
    char line[256];
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, 256, fp)) {
        // Handling blank lines
        if (strcmp(line, "\n") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Parsing line 
        char* label = NULL;
        char* instruction = NULL;
        char* directive = NULL;
        char* operands = NULL;
        label = strtok(line, ":");
        instruction = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        directive = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        operands = strtok(NULL, "\n\t");

        // Handling instructions
        if (instruction) {
            // Parsing instruction
            int opcode = 0;
            int funct = 0;
            int rs = 0;
            int rt = 0;
            int rd = 0;
            int imm = 0;
            int add = 0;
            
        if (parseInstruction(instruction, &opcode, &funct)) {
            rs = getRegisterNumber(strtok(operands, ","));
            rt = getRegisterNumber(strtok(NULL, ","));
        if (opcode == 0) {
            rd = getRegisterNumber(strtok(NULL, ","));
        } else {
        imm = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        }
         // Generating machine code
        int machine_code = 0;
        machine_code |= (opcode << 26);
        machine_code |= (rs << 21);
        machine_code |= (rt << 16);
        machine_code |= (rd << 11);
        machine_code |= (imm << 0);
        machine_code |= (add << 0);
        machine_code |= (funct << 0);
    // Writing machine code to text segment
        text_segment[text_offset] = machine_code;
        text_offset += 1;
        }
        // Handling directives
        if (directive) {
            // Parsing directive
            int type = 0;
            int size = 0;
            if (parseDirective(directive, &type, &size)) {
                char* token = strtok(operands, ",");
                while (token) {
                    int value = 0;
                    sscanf(token, "%d", &value);

                    // Handling .dbyte
                    if (type == 2) {
                        data_segment;
                        // Writing value to data segments
                        data_segment[data_offset] = value;
                        data_offset += 1;
                    }

                    // Handling .integer
                    if (type == 3) {
                        // Writing value to data segment
                        data_segment[data_offset] = value;
                        data_offset += 1;
                    }

                    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

// Getting MIPS instruction
Instruction* getInstruction(char* instruction) {
    int i = 0;

    while (instructions[i].name) {
        if (strcmp(instructions[i].name, instruction) == 0) {
            return &instructions[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Getting MIPS directive
Directive* getDirective(char* directive) {
    int i = 0;

    while (directives[i].name) {
        if (strcmp(directives[i].name, directive)) { 
            return &directives[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Getting register number
int getRegisterNumber(char* regis) {
    int reg = 0;
    sscanf(regis, "$%d", &reg);
    return reg;
}


// Parsing instruction
int parseInstruction(char* instruction, int* opcode, int* funct) {
    for (int i = 0; instructions[i].name; i++) {
        if (strcmp(instruction, instructions[i].name) == 0) {
            *opcode = instructions[i].opcode;
            *funct = instructions[i].funct;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Parsing directive
int parseDirective(char* directive, int* type, int* size) {
    Directive* dir = getDirective(directive);
    if (dir) {
        *type = dir->n;
        *size = dir->size;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Note your code (as posted) will not compile because you're missing a closing `}` in `assemble`. This probably causes some of your issues. Also, you call `parseInstruction` before it is defined. I'd use forward function declarations or reorder to functions.

Comment: how would i go about declaring that? I have spent countless hours on this project

Comment: also the assemble } bracket is all the way at the bottom unless i posted wrong, or is it not supposed to be there? I wrote the entirety of the assemble to include all of the things that followed it

Comment: Yes, you have the correct number of `}` but the final `}` is in the wrong place, so the compiler thinks you have lexically "nested" functions (which don't exist in standard C).

Comment: I figured out where the missing bracket after continue was so i deleted the superfluous one at the end, now its having difficulty running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefaced by the top comments ...

> Note your code (as posted) will not compile because you're missing a closing `}` in `assemble`. This probably causes some of your issues. Also, you call `parseInstruction` before it is defined. I'd use forward function declarations or reorder the functions. –
> Craig Estey

> how would i go about declaring that? I have spent countless hours on this project –
> Andrew Schelb

> also the assemble } bracket is all the way at the bottom unless i posted wrong, or is it not supposed to be there? I wrote the entirety of the assemble to include all of the things that followed it –
> Andrew Schelb

> Yes, you have the correct number of `}` but the final `}` is in the wrong place, so the compiler thinks you have lexically "nested" functions (which don't exist in standard C). –
> Craig Estey

---

Okay, I've refactored the code so it will compile cleanly. It still has one warning about setting `label` but *not* using it.

I had to synthesize some of your *missing* `struct` definitions to get it to compile cleanly.

But, this solves your original issue with regard to the missing functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// synthesized missing definitions ...
#if 1
#define MAX_SIZE    1024

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int n;
    int size;
} Directive;

Directive directives[1000];

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int opcode;
    int funct;
} Instruction;

Instruction instructions[1000];

#endif

// forward function declarations
#if 1
void assemble(char *filename, int *text_segment, int *data_segment);
Instruction *getInstruction(char *instruction);
Directive *getDirective(char *directive);
int getRegisterNumber(char *regis);
int parseInstruction(char *instruction, int *opcode, int *funct);
int parseDirective(char *directive, int *type, int *size);
#endif

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Checking command line arguments
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <test.asm> <test.out>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Initializing memory
    int text_segment[MAX_SIZE];
    int data_segment[MAX_SIZE];

// NOTE/BUG: compiler warns about third arg being too small
#if 0
    memset(text_segment, 0, MAX_SIZE);
    memset(data_segment, 0, MAX_SIZE);
#else
    memset(text_segment, 0, sizeof(text_segment));
    memset(data_segment, 0, sizeof(data_segment));
#endif

    // Writing to output file
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    fwrite(text_segment, 1, MAX_SIZE, fp);
    fwrite(data_segment, 1, MAX_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

// Assembling the input file
void
assemble(char *filename, int *text_segment, int *data_segment)
{
// NOTE/BUG: line_number not used
#if 0
    int line_number = 0;
#endif
    int text_offset = 0;
    int data_offset = 0;
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, 256, fp)) {
        // Handling blank lines
        if (strcmp(line, "\n") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Parsing line
// NOTE/BUG: compiler warning: label set but not used
        char *label = NULL;
        char *instruction = NULL;
        char *directive = NULL;
        char *operands = NULL;

        label = strtok(line, ":");
        instruction = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        directive = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        operands = strtok(NULL, "\n\t");

        // Handling instructions
        if (instruction) {
            // Parsing instruction
            int opcode = 0;
            int funct = 0;
            int rs = 0;
            int rt = 0;
            int rd = 0;
            int imm = 0;
            int add = 0;

            if (parseInstruction(instruction, &opcode, &funct)) {
                rs = getRegisterNumber(strtok(operands, ","));
                rt = getRegisterNumber(strtok(NULL, ","));
                if (opcode == 0) {
                    rd = getRegisterNumber(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                else {
                    imm = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                // Generating machine code
                int machine_code = 0;

                machine_code |= (opcode << 26);
                machine_code |= (rs << 21);
                machine_code |= (rt << 16);
                machine_code |= (rd << 11);
                machine_code |= (imm << 0);
                machine_code |= (add << 0);
                machine_code |= (funct << 0);
                // Writing machine code to text segment
                text_segment[text_offset] = machine_code;
                text_offset += 1;
            }
            // Handling directives
            if (directive) {
                // Parsing directive
                int type = 0;
                int size = 0;

                if (parseDirective(directive, &type, &size)) {
                    char *token = strtok(operands, ",");

                    while (token) {
                        int value = 0;

                        sscanf(token, "%d", &value);

                        // Handling .dbyte
                        if (type == 2) {
// NOTE/BUG: statement with no effect
#if 0
                            data_segment;
#endif
                            // Writing value to data segments
                            data_segment[data_offset] = value;
                            data_offset += 1;
                        }

                        // Handling .integer
                        if (type == 3) {
                            // Writing value to data segment
                            data_segment[data_offset] = value;
                            data_offset += 1;
                        }

                        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
}

// Getting MIPS instruction
Instruction *
getInstruction(char *instruction)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (instructions[i].name) {
        if (strcmp(instructions[i].name, instruction) == 0) {
            return &instructions[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Getting MIPS directive
Directive *
getDirective(char *directive)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (directives[i].name) {
        if (strcmp(directives[i].name, directive)) {
            return &directives[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Getting register number
int
getRegisterNumber(char *regis)
{
    int reg = 0;

    sscanf(regis, "$%d", &reg);
    return reg;
}

// Parsing instruction
int
parseInstruction(char *instruction, int *opcode, int *funct)
{
    for (int i = 0; instructions[i].name; i++) {
        if (strcmp(instruction, instructions[i].name) == 0) {
            *opcode = instructions[i].opcode;
            *funct = instructions[i].funct;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Parsing directive
int
parseDirective(char *directive, int *type, int *size)
{
    Directive *dir = getDirective(directive);

    if (dir) {
        *type = dir->n;
        *size = dir->size;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Comment: I was able to get it to to compile and build now i need it to run using an input file of test.asm and output test.out to read each instruction